# How can I improve this basic jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

I'm just starting to get my hands dirty with some basic jQuery. I want to be able to add a "defaultValue" attribute to any textbox and then have the box cleared on focus and then the default value reinserted into the textbox if the value is blank. I've come up with a basic couple of function to do this, but is there a better way? I seem to recall seeing some examples of jQuery functions that don't rely on two separate methods...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=text]').click(function () {
            var defaultValue = $(this).attr('defaultValue');
            if ($(this).val() == defaultValue)
                $(this).val('');
        });
        $('input[type=text]').blur(function () {
            var defaultValue = $(this).attr('defaultValue');
            if ($(this).val() == '')
                $(this).val(defaultValue);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Watch out for situations where the user actually wants to enter the defaultValue as their input (may or may not be an issue for you depending on what you're doing with it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type=text]').focus(function () {
        if (this.value == this.defaultValue)
            this.value = '';
    })
     .blur(function () {
        if ( !$.trim( this.value ) )
            this.value = this.defaultValue;
    });
});
```

- Use the `$(function() {   });` shortcut for `.ready()`
- Use `.focus()` instead of `.click()`
- Only select `$('input[type=text]')` from the DOM once. You can chain method calls against a jQuery object.
- Don't use `.val()` to get the `value` and `defaultValue` of a `text` input. They are accessible directly from the element's property name with full cross-browser compatibility.
- If you wanted, you could shorten the selector from `'input[type=text]'` to `'input:text'`

---

**EDIT:** Removed a stray `)`.

Also, based on [@jAndy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305000/jandy) suggestion, the expression in the `if()` statement of the `blur` event has been changed to test for strings that have only space characters<s>. I used the unary `+` operator to do this. An alternative as suggested by jAndy would be to use</s> [using] jQuery's `$.trim()` method.

If you want a single function for both events, you could do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type=text]').bind('focus blur', function ( e ) {
        if (e.type === 'focus' && this.value == this.defaultValue)
            this.value = '';
        else if (e.type === 'blur' && !$.trim( this.value ) )
            this.value = this.defaultValue;
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT:** Changed it to use `$.trim()` as @jAndy originally suggested, since the `+` will give an improper result when the input is `"0"`, or like `"   0   "`.

Comment: for a shorter selector, you could use `$(":text")`

Comment: @nickf: Very true. Updated, although you don't want just `:text`, because it will test *every* element on the page, instead of just `<input>` elements.

Comment: @jAndy: That's exactly what you should use. See the last bullet point in my answer. ;o)

Comment: @patrick: calling `$.trim` on `this.value` may also be a good idea :) `if (!$.trim(this.value).length)`

Comment: @jAndy: Do you mean in the `blur` handler when testing for white space in an empty string? If so, good point, but I think I'd rather use the unary `+` operator. I'll update.

Comment: @patrick: sure, but this will only work properly on numeric values. `NaN != 0`

Comment: @jAndy: The result of using a unary `+` against an empty string, or a string with only spaces is `0`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CHnVT/) The number conversion works differently from the boolean conversion.

Comment: @jAndy: If you're interested, from Section 9.3.1 in the spec: *"A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is converted to +0."* and *"The MV [mathematical value] of StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty] is 0. The MV of StringNumericLiteral ::: StrWhiteSpace is 0."*

Comment: @patrick: it is really interesting. Another nice usecase for this operator.

Comment: @jAndy: One flaw that I'll need to fix. If the input actually is `'0'`, or like `'  0  '`, it isn't empty, yet will be overwritten with the `defaultValue`. I may just switch to using your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great comments. This is why I love this site.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share the very same function I wrote yesterday.

Difference to not is that it greys out the default text, selects all on focus, changes text color and mainly: It sets the default text on load instead (obviously toss inside $(func )

```
  $('input:text').each(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).css('color','#999');
        $(this).focus(function(){
            // If value is same as 'placeholder', clear field
            if(this.value == $(this).attr('placeholder')
                && $(this).css("color") == 'rgb(153, 153, 153)'){
                $(this).val('').css('color','#000');
            } else { // Else select the whole text (one less click)
                $(this).select();
            }
        });
        $(this).blur(function(){
            // On blur, if empty field, put placeholdr back
            if (!$.trim( this.value)){
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).css('color','#999');
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm sure it can be made better, but it works well.